# What's the cleanest way of iterating over a dict with a nested list in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have 2 dicts with the following structure:

```yaml
# this will be set in the role

knative_base_urls:
  serving: 
    url: "https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/{{ knative_serving_version }}/"
  eventing: 
    url: "https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/{{ knative_eventing_version }}/"
  eventing-contrib: 
    url: "https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/{{ knative_eventing_version }}/"
  monitoring: 
    url: "https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/{{ knative_monitoring_version }}/"

# this will be provided by the end user
knative_install_components:
  serving:
    install:
    - serving.yaml
    - foo.yaml
  eventing:
    install:
    - release.yaml
  eventing-contrib:
    install:
    - event-display.yaml
```

I have figured out a way of merging them using `{{ knative_base_urls | combine(knative_install_components, recursive=true) }}`, which gives me the following structure:

```yaml
knative_yamls:
    eventing:
      install:
      - release.yaml
      url: https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/
    eventing-contrib:
      install:
      - event-display.yaml
      url: https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/v0.11.0/
    monitoring:
      url: https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download//
    serving:
      install:
      - serving.yaml
      - foo.yaml
      url: https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/
```

But where I am stuck, is that I cannot figure out a way to loop over/transform this data, so that I can successfully loop over the list of URLs and filenames.

The difficulty is that each one of the `install` keys can contain a list of many files, which then should be mapped to the base url of their parent component.

```
- name: Compile list of Knative components to install
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.value.url }}{{ item.value.install }}"
  with_dict: "{{ knative_base_urls | combine(knative_install_components, recursive=true) }}"
  when: item.value.install is defined

# output

TASK [ratings-ansible-role-knative : Compile list of Knative components to install] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'serving', 'value': {'url': 'https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/', 'install': ['serving.yaml', 'foo.yaml']}}) =>
  msg: https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/['serving.yaml', 'foo.yaml']
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'eventing', 'value': {'url': 'https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/', 'install': ['release.yaml']}}) =>
  msg: https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/['release.yaml']
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'eventing-contrib', 'value': {'url': 'https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/v0.11.0/', 'install': ['event-display.yaml']}}) =>
  msg: https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/v0.11.0/['event-display.yaml']
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'monitoring', 'value': {'url': 'https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download//'}})
```

What is the "cleanest" way of getting this done in Ansible?

I could easily break those out into a task for each one of the components, but I'd like to find out the best way of accomplishing this to satisfy my own personal curiosity :).

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be easier and cleaner that I was anticipating!

Here's a sample task definition which simply prints the results out:

```yaml
- name: print
  debug:
    msg: "url: {{ item.0.url }}, file: {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ knative_yamls }}"
    - install
    - skip_missing: true
```

Output:

```json
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/'}, 'serving.yaml']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/, file: serving.yaml'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/'}, 'foo.yaml']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/, file: foo.yaml'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/'}, 'many']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/, file: many'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/'}, 'more']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.1/, file: more'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/'}, 'release.yaml']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/, file: release.yaml'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/'}, 'yamls']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/, file: yamls'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'url': 'https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/v0.11.0/'}, 'event-display.yaml']) =>
  msg: 'url: https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/v0.11.0/, file: event-display.yaml'
```